# parallel pg_restore with materialized views

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, pg-restore

I am trying to restore a database that includes some materialized views. I am migrating from a standalone postgres installation to RDS.

To troubleshoot the restore process, I have split the restore into 5 steps using the `--section` and the `-L` option. The steps are

1. Restore the `pre-data` section, but without materialized views, `-j 1`
2. Restore the `data` section in parallel, `-j 5`
3. Restore the `post-data` section in parallel, `-j 5`
4. Restore the materialized views, creation section (`pre-data`), `-j 1`
5. Restore the materialized views, refresh section (`post-data`) in parallel `-j 5`

Steps 1-4 runs without any problems. In step 5 I run into trouble. The step takes forever and if I list the `pg_stat_activity` I can see two processes that runs the same `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`

```
-[ RECORD 3 ]---------------------------------------------------
pid     | 17244
query   | REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW home_property_data;
        | 
        | 
        | 
waiting | f
... snip ...
-[ RECORD 7 ]---------------------------------------------------
pid     | 17243
query   | REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW home_property_data;
        | 
waiting | f
```

If I read the documentation for the MATERIALIZED views it looks like that they cannot be updated in parallel. Am I doing the restore wrong ?

Comment: You're running the step 5 in parallel. Is there a chance the list of parallel jobs to be run include refreshing `home_property_data` twice as two separate jobs?

Comment: "If I read the documentation for the MATERIALIZED views it looks like that they cannot be updated in parallel." can you please link or quote where you get this impression from.